# Custom ArrayAdapter Not Just First Element Different

Tags: android, listview

I'm working on making a custom ArrayAdapter so that my list has the first element in a different color.

The thing is, when I execute this code in the get view method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    Club club = (Club)getItem(position);
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtListItem);
    if(position == 0 && club.getName().contains("All")){
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.orange));
    }
    textView.setText(club.getName());
    return convertView;
}
```

The first item is orange, yes, but the 10th one (below the screen) is also when I scroll down :( in another list with more elements than what the screen can hold, I have several that are orange.. I don't understand why, please help!

Comment: Please include the enclosing method declaration so we don't have to look it up. Thank you.

Comment: The simple answer is that you are setting the color to orange, but then the adapter reuses that view, and it's still orange. So you'll get orange views peppered throughout your list. The key is to set the view BACK to default colors if it DOESN'T meet your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because views are recycling/reused. You are setting orange color for the first item but not setting default color for the rest. Just add an `else` clause to your `if` statement above, something like this

```
 if(position == 0 && club.getName().contains("All")){
    Log.d(ClubAdapter.class.getName(), club.getName());
    textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.orange));
}else{
    textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.your_default_color));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this happens because Android is recycling the view which was originally used for the first row. You need an `else` clause to set the color back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the adapter tries to reuse as many views as possible for performance improvement. That's why you should not create a view in getView, but reuse them (only create if it is null):

```
if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
```

Even though you shouldn't create a new view, you have to make sure that you set the parameters that you want for each getView call (also called "binding"), so:

```
if(position == 0){
    //set your first view color and whatever
}else{
    //set your common view colors..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because listview recycle views Google suggests to use the ViewHolder pattern. You should also set a default color if the cell is different. It would look something like this.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtListItem);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(position == 0 && club.getName().contains("All")){
        viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.orange));
    }else{
        //Set default color
    }

    viewHolder.textView.setText(club.getName());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView textView;

}
```